# Get combinations between two given ones

Tags: c, combinations

Are there already any implementations in C (or c++) for generating all possible combinations of n elements in groups of p elements, but starting at a given combination and ending in another given one?

Something important is not to generate/store all possible combinations and then get the ones needed.

For example: If I want combinations of unsigned ints less than 10, with five numbers per combination, and I only want to see combinations numbered 50--54 (for some consistent numbering of combinations), I would call

`combination(10, 5, 50, 54)` which would return somenthing like

```
50 (0, 1, 5, 7, 8)
51 (0, 1, 5, 7, 9)
52 (0, 1, 5, 8, 9)
53 (0, 1, 6, 7, 8)
54 (0, 1, 6, 7, 9)
```

Comment: It would be a good idea to explain what the arguments to your fictional `combination()` actually are. It took me a bit to figure out what was going on.

Comment: The breakdown would be: (1) generate the combination by its lexicographical number, (2) generate the next combination given the current one. Both can be rather efficient, see e.g. Theorem L and Algorithm T in [this part](http://www.kcats.org/csci/464/doc/knuth/fascicles/fasc3a.pdf) of Knuth's fourth volume of TAOCP.

Comment: Here is an article on how to do this (though you need a membership to access it): http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=355739. At the very least it will give you other terms to Google.

Comment: Somehow I forgot and mentally switched to permutations as I tabbed out to google... Thanks

Comment: You've asked for existing implementations. There are probably some, but I don't know of any. But you can roll your own. I wanted to post an answer, but I was too late. I've written some [commented-code-as-asnwer](https://ideone.com/7SzhId) instead, which you might find useful.

Comment: @MOehm I gave your code a try and I got to say that it runs incredibly fast.

Comment: @MOehm but I found something and I don't know why it doesn't work. Instead of the combination of 10 elements in groups of 5, I tried with a larger set of numbers: 76 elements in groups of 8. In theory there should be 18855883575 combinations, but the last one the program generates is 295489472 (although well generated, I mean, it prints `295489472: {68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75}`). The last thing I don't understand is why it works when I set `start = 295488979` and `end = 295501739` but it won't generate any combination if I start at, for example,  `start = 295488980` and `end = 295501739`

Comment: Yes, you've run into integer overflow. An `int` can only hold numbers of up to about 2 billion. In a footnote to the code, I say that the indices should be `unit64_t`, a 64-bit unsigned type. Instead of hiding this in a a note, I should have implemented that. [I have now](https://ideone.com/be73YS) and your example works. But the problem isn't solved, it will still occur with bigger numbers.